# In Python, None evaluates to less than zero?

Tags: python, python-2.x

**In Python, `None` evaluates to less than zero?**

```
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:21:10) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> None < 0
True
>>> None == 0
False
>>> None > 0
False
>>>
```

Is this expected?

I would have guessed that `None` would either be equal to zero (through type coercion), or that all of these statements would return `False`.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can't do that any more in Python 3. It will give you this error: `TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()`

Comment: @NullUserException: that's good to know. Because this is not the kind of intuitive behaviour that I expect from Python.

Comment: Don't forget, even though it is dynamically typed, Python is still **strongly** typed: that is, no implicit coercions are performed.

Comment: @Daniel They are if you compare a `bool` to an `int` (or at least so it seems)

Comment: To expand on @NullUserException, the bools are actually explicitly stated to be very thin wrappers around the integer constants `0` and `1` with special `__str__` and `__repr__`. Math, logic and everything else works exactly the same on both, `bool` is even a subclass of `int`. That's as much of an implicit conversion as `1 + 1.0` resulting in a float.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result).

and

> **CPython implementation detail:** Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Comment: I like the part where it says, "ordered consistently but arbitrarily."  How useful...

Comment: Yes it is. you usually want sorting operations to yield the same results every time you use them.

Comment: vague but just enough :)

Comment: What does "consistently but arbitrarily" mean?

Answer (score 5):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> **CPython implementation detail:** Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

`NoneType` compares as smaller than `int` since the comparison appears to be case-sensitive.

```
>>> type(0)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(None)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> 'NoneType' < 'int'
True
```

Comment: This can't be right, since `print(5 > {})` gives you false, and `int > dict`

Comment: @NullUserException: Interesting. That would seem to contradict the documentation, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @NullUserException: `type(5) > type({})` gives false, so that part is consistent, though I'm not sure why they compare that way when, as you said, `int > dict`. However, `type(None) > type(0)`. Hmm....

Comment: @NullUserException @hammar - I get `int < dict` here, on Python 2.6.6. But also the inconsistent `type(None) > type(0)` but `None < 0`...

Comment: @NullUserException: The doc says "Objects of different types **except numbers**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: you're just comparing two strings
>>> 'N' < 'i'
True

Comment: @detly There is no inconsistency with the None and 0. Both are constant objects in Python. Instruction `None < 0` results into `'NoneType' < 'int'`, but instruction `type(None) > type(0)` results into comparing same types, so addresses are used: `id(type(None)) > id(type(0))` equals to `505392864 > 505387040` in my case.

Answer (score 3):

It is intentional to make operations like sorting and dictionary comparison well defined.

[citing from the [Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html)]

> The operators <, >, ==, >=, <=, and != compare the values of two
>   objects. The objects need not have the same type. If both are numbers,
>   they are converted to a common type. Otherwise, objects of different
>   types always compare unequal, and are ordered consistently but
>   arbitrary.